# Does SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT) support migrating whole on-premises site to online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, site-collection, migration, sharepointmigrationtool

I have a question if does SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT) supports migrating whole on-premises sites which contain lists and libraries to SharePoint online? or it only support migrating documents?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT) supports migrating sites as well.

Here are the different Migration types supported using the SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT):

[image]

**Microsoft Documentations**:

1. [Overview of the SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool)
2. [Create a migration task with SPMT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/spmt-create-task)

Comment: then is there a need to use commercial migration tools such as sharegate if this free migration tool can do the migration for the onprem sites?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. There are some limitations of SPMT as well, check: https://sharegate.com/blog/our-take-microsoft-free-sharepoint-migration-tool